# Display only author posts in dashboard all posts panel

Tags: author, deprecation

I would like to display only authors own posts in dashboard all posts section. As of now it displays everything.

I found some code [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-only-authors-posts-in-admin-panel-instead-of-all-posts?replies=32) which is written by @t31os Its working correctly.

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
    global $user_level;

    if($query->is_admin && $user_level < 5) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
        unset($user_ID);
    }
    unset($user_level);

    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

But user_level is deprecated.  So can anyone modify the code for new version?
Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the [*Roles and Capabilities* that wordpress offers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) by default? Especially [Author](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Author) - Somebody who can publish and manage their own posts

Comment: Yes i'm aware of roles and caps. But i'm trying to give permissions to submit content for all registered users (subscribers). But I don't want to list all posts

Comment: Okay, I see. As `$user_level` is deprecated, you might be able to check for it's role(s) then instead.

Comment: Can you give me the code? I tried but its not working.

Comment: You only need to replace the `$user_level` with the appropriate role, see [Roles and Capabilities: User Levels](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#User_Levels) which level relates to which role.

Comment: Yes i understand all that roles and caps thing. But I should replace with what? Lets say i need only editors and admins can view all posts. I should replace with what? you mean like `$level_5` instead of `$user_level` The above code uses query stuffs. I really have no knowledge in that query stuff. So i really appreciate if you can just copy the above code and replace it with the cap of author. Thanks

Comment: No, you need to get the roles of the user (e.g. admin), compare against (admin, editor), if it matches, do that action. That's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following worked for me to show only the current user's posts in the admin

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'posts_for_current_author' );
function posts_for_current_author() {
    global $user_ID;

    /*if current user is an 'administrator' do nothing*/
    //if ( current_user_can( 'add_users' ) ) return;

    /*if current user is an 'administrator' or 'editor' do nothing*/
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_others_pages' ) ) return;

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['author'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'author', $user_ID ) );
        exit;
    }

}
```

It can be edited pretty easily if the restriction should only happen for users in a particular role.

Comment: You are a diamond mate. It worked like a charm. Thank you so much